# Webpack. Использование import/export вместо require/module.exports

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, commonjs

Как настроить Webpack понимать инструкции import/export вместо синтаксиса CommonJS?

Пытаюсь экспортировать объект

```html
const babelConfig = {
  babelrc: false,
  presets: [
    'react-app'
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['babel-plugin-styled-components', {
      displayName: isDevelopment,
      minify: false
    }]
  ]
}

export default babelConfig
```

и получаю ошибку

```html
$ node scripts/start.js 
/myproject/config/babel-config.js:19
export default babelConfig
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Comment: Логично, потому что node не использует babel.

Comment: @Qwertiy я заметил) есть способ использовать ES6 синтакс?

Comment: `node-babel` вместо `node`.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо! тоже дошел по вопросам enSO, добью - набросаю ответ

Comment: конфиг вебпака выполняется в ноде и ничего общего с бандлом и сайтом не имеет, поэтому непонятно зачем это надо? можете его транспилировать перед запуском проекта или использовать ноду 10 с экспериментальным флагом

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko вот как раз транспилировать перед запуском проекта хочу, не понимает import/export

Comment: нужно что-то вроде `node -r babel/register scripts/start.js` + .babelrc с соответствующими настройками

Comment: хотя не очень понятно зачем это надо :)

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko писать конфиги на последних стандартах

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko хотя вы правы) чего я выпендриваюсь, можно писать на языке ноды